# PhpStorm not reading app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, phpstorm

I'm a PhpStorm newbie. I've setup my plugins for Google App Engine and I can run my pages and scripts locally fine. The problem is that I can't navigate to another page.

My app.yaml has an entry that says:

```
- url: /properties
script: properties.php
```

And my hyperlink to this page is simply:

```
<a href="properties">Properties</a>
```

When I run this site in GAE's launcher, the link works i.e. "properties" is requested and the yaml tells the server to serve "properties.php". When I run it in PhpStorm, I get a 404 error because it is is requesting "properties" which does not exist. This tells me that PhpStorm is serving php correctly, but not the GAE environment. Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

It's worth mentioning that my project is being run with a Google App Engine configuration.

The SDK directory is: /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine

Python executable is: /usr/bin/python

And the 404 page says "PhpStorm 10.0.3" in the footer.

Comment: 1) What the URL looks like in a browser 2) I assume you have seen [this article](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Getting+Started+with+PhpStorm+as+Google+App+Engine+PHP+IDE) already?

Comment: Thanks LazyOne - I had read that article many times. I resolved by installing php-cgi using home brew. Then I ran into another problem where the python script was asking for input re checking updates - running the script outside of phpstorm once fixed that issue and now everything is working as expected.